# Automatic sorting of new folders Windows

Tags: windows, windows-scripting, system-administration, windows-administration

I know about setting sorting for parent folders and stuff.
But when creating a new folder in Windows, sorting is by name. Is it possible to change some value in the registry or create some script for the action of creating a folder - so that sorting by date is automatically set.
That is, I would like it to be without any additional actions, well, there must be system settings somewhere in Windows? Even setting for all folders in the system of such a value will do.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1.Open file explorer

2.Open any folder, then select View from the top menu

3.Click on Date modified to sort by most recent

4.Select Options from the far right top menu then choose Change folder and search options

5.Select View tab, Apply to all folders

6.Create a test folder and refresh to see if it gets sorted by date

You can also refer to this answer

https://superuser.com/questions/49591/how-do-i-change-the-default-sort-order-on-windows-explorer-and-the-file-dialogs

Comment: Checked on Windows 10 and no, this does not apply to new folders (i.e. created a new one and sorted by name there..)

Comment: @Vixer This has worked for me on Windows10. After you follow the steps and create a folder, refresh and check it. It works for all folders and every time.